# paragraphs_update_8018 takes very long time to finish

Tags: 8, paragraphs

The `paragraphs_update_8018` update takes very long to complete (we have over 1 mio. paragraphs), as of now it's already been over 1h40m and it's still running. EDIT: it finished after 1h47m

My question is: is it possible to run this update without maintenance mode? I don't want to take the site down for so long for this update.

Comment: See https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs/issues/3044023

Comment: I am using Paragraphs Version 1.9.0 so that patch is already included. And I don't have a timeout, it just takes very long. The update actually finished after 1h47m.

Comment: Maybe try running updates on the command line with Drush: `drush updb`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a [known bug](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs/issues/3044023) in a third-party module, tracked and fixed on drupal.org.

Comment: @leymannx I do use `drush updb`. And the version 1.9 that I am using has this bug already fixed. My problem is not a bug, but just how long the update takes. I'd like to know if it's a possibility to run this update without maintenance mode on production.

Comment: Maybe remove unused paragraphs first. But this is dangerous when the editorial workflow heavily relies on node revisions. https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs_clean

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer: act on your own risk!**

After looking into what this update exactly does, I decided to execute it without maintenance mode. It worked without any problems. It depends on your situation though. You have to make sure that nothing interferes with the tables in question (no editors editing paragraphs, no automatic content imports/updates etc.).

Note that `drush updb` automatically enables maintenance mode, you have to disable it explicitly.

Of course generally speaking it's not a good idea to disable the maintenance mode during `drush updb` and problems may occur.

Comment: To prevent paragraphs editing, we copied permissionless versions of admin role configs to `config/partial/disable_admin`, then before updb we ran `drush cim sync --partial --source=config/partial/disable_admin`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the query instead of the default drupal update method for this update

```
 UPDATE paragraphs_item_revision_field_data
 INNER JOIN paragraphs_item_field_data  ON (paragraphs_item_revision_field_data.id = 
 paragraphs_item_field_data.id && paragraphs_item_field_data.parent_id IS NOT NULL)
 SET paragraphs_item_revision_field_data.parent_id = 
 paragraphs_item_field_data.parent_id,paragraphs_item_revision_field_data.parent_type 
 = paragraphs_item_field_data.parent_type,
 paragraphs_item_revision_field_data.parent_field_name = 
 paragraphs_item_field_data.parent_field_name where 
 paragraphs_item_revision_field_data.parent_id IS NULL;
```

as mentioned by [btobac](http://btobac.com/blog/paragraphs-update-8018-fails-or-takes-too-long-or-exceeded-timeout-fixed-drupal-8)